# How to pass intent from 1st activity to second and viceversa?

Tags: android

I have two activities both xml files have an edittext and a button.I want to pass intent of first activity to second and also from second activity to first my teacher have said me to  use ON ACTIVITY RESULT AND START ACTIVITY FOR RESULT METHODS

please help me i am a newcomer and its my homework!!!

Comment: How much marks assigned for this question ?

Comment: Search the Android documentation for Intents and Activities. It will all be explained over there.

Comment: you want to pass the intent or you want to fire the intent with startActivityForResult(..)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android, How to manage start activity for result?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/android-how-to-manage-start-activity-for-result)